# QML SwipeView addItem causing QML ListView: possible QQuickItem::polish() loop error

Tags: qt, qml

EDIT: I have no idea what was causing this issue. I got extremely frustrated and created a new project with similar code and it works fine. Thanks guys!

ORIGINAL POST:

I have a swipe view that I add items to dynamically via a button press. When the application starts up it adds a default set of pages to the stack view, in this example "AddPage" is added. This works fine. Upon clicking the button on the "AddPage" page, the user is presented with a different SwipeView of options and an accept button. A section is made and then the accept button is pressed. When the accept button is pressed it emits a signal "startAddGauge" which is connected to the acceptClicked slot shown below. When I test this code I get the following output repeating until the application crashes:

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlEngine::setContextForObject(): Object already has a QQmlContext
qml: addPage()
qml: Adding new style: Single Arc Gauge
qml: addPage()
file:///Users/ajdecker/Qt/6.0.1/clang_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Material/SwipeView.qml:49:18: QML ListView: possible QQuickItem::polish() loop
file:///Users/ajdecker/Qt/6.0.1/clang_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Material/SwipeView.qml:49:18: QML ListView: ListView called polish() inside updatePolish() of ListView
file:///Users/ajdecker/Qt/6.0.1/clang_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Material/SwipeView.qml:49:18: QML ListView: possible QQuickItem::polish() loop
file:///Users/ajdecker/Qt/6.0.1/clang_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Material/SwipeView.qml:49:18: QML ListView: ListView called polish() inside updatePolish() of ListView
```

I do not understand what is happening here other than some type of infinite loop. Can anyone provide any hints as to what would cause this error?

Below are the relevant files.

main.qml

```
SwipeView {
    id: viewSwipe
    anchors.fill: parent
    currentIndex: 0
    property int curIndexWitouthZero: 0

    Component.onCompleted: {
        curIndexWitouthZero = viewSwipe.currentIndex
        curIndexWitouthZero += 1
        var addPagePage = createPage("qrc:/AddGaugeBase.qml");
        addPagePage.availableGaugeStyles.startAddGauge.connect(acceptClicked);
        addPage(addPagePage) //Add the AddGauge page
        //TODO: Add the main menu page
    }

    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        curIndexWitouthZero = viewSwipe.currentIndex
        curIndexWitouthZero += 1
    }

    function addPage(page) {
        console.log("addPage()")
        insertItem(count - 1, page);
        page.visible = true
    }
    function createPage(pageFileName){
        var component = Qt.createComponent(pageFileName);
        var page = component.createObject(viewSwipe);
        return page
    }

    function acceptClicked(name)
    {
        console.log("Adding new style: "+name);
        addPage(createPage("qrc:/TestGaugeStyle.qml"));
    }
}
```

AddGaugeBase.qml

```
StackView {
// TODO: Adjust transitions so the views in the stack transition
// from the bottom up or top down
id: viewStack
anchors.fill: parent
initialItem: addGauge
property alias availableGaugeStyles: availableGaugeStyles
AddGauge
{
    id: addGauge
    addButton.onClicked: {
        viewStack.push(availableGaugeStyles)
    }
}
AvailableGaugeStyles{
    id: availableGaugeStyles
    visible: viewStack.currentItem === availableGaugeStyles
    cancelButton.onClicked: {
        viewStack.pop(null)
    }
}
}
```

AddGauge.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4

AddGaugeForm {
    addButton.onExited: add.opacity = 1.0
    addButton.onEntered: add.opacity = 0.7
}
```

AddGaugeForm.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Item {
    id: addGaugePage
    property alias addButton: addButton
    property alias add: add
    Image {
        id: background
        width: 400
        height: 400
        x: 0
        y: 0
        source: "qrc:/images/background.svg"
    }
    Image {
        id: add
        x: 160
        y: 160
        source: "qrc:/buttons/add.svg"
        MouseArea {
            id: addButton
            acceptedButtons: Qt.AllButtons
            width: add.width
            height: add.height
        }
    }
}
```

AvailableGaugeStyles.qml

```
AvailableGaugeStylesForm {
    signal startAddGauge(string styleNam)
    acceptButton.onClicked: startAddGauge(availableGaugePresenters.get(availableGaugePresentersPicker.currentItem).name)
}
```

AvailableGaugeStylesForm.qml

```
Item {
id: availabeGaugesPage
width: 400
height: 400
property alias acceptButton: acceptButton
property alias cancelButton: cancelButton
property alias availableGaugePresentersPicker: availableGaugePresentersPicker
property alias availableGaugePresenters: availableGaugePresenters

Image {
    id: background
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    source: "qrc:/images/background.svg"
}

Image {
    id: arcbuttontopcancel
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    y: 0
    source: "qrc:/buttons/arc-button-top-cancel.svg"
    MouseArea {
        id: cancelButton
        anchors.fill: parent
        onEntered: arcbuttontopcancel.opacity = 0.7
        onExited: arcbuttontopcancel.opacity = 1
    }
}

Image {
    id: arcbuttonbottomaccept
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    y: 280
    source: "qrc:/buttons/arc-button-bottom-accept.svg"
    MouseArea {
        id: acceptButton
        anchors.fill: parent
        onEntered: arcbuttonbottomaccept.opacity = 0.7
        onExited: arcbuttonbottomaccept.opacity = 1
    }
}

ListModel {
    id: availableGaugePresenters
    ListElement {
        name: "Single Arc Gauge"
        dataPresenterCount: 1
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Dual Arc Gauge"
        dataPresenterCount: 2
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Quad Arc Gauge"
        dataPresenterCount: 4
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Single Dial Gauge"
        dataPresenterCount: 1
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Dual Dial Gauge"
        dataPresenterCount: 2
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Quad Dial Gauge"
        dataPresenterCount: 4
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Single Digital Gauge"
        dataPresenterCount: 1
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Dual Digital Gauge"
        dataPresenterCount: 2
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Triple Digital Gauge"
        dataPresenterCount: 3
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Quad Digital Gauge"
        dataPresenterCount: 4
    }
}

SwipeView {
    id: availableGaugePresentersPicker
    width: 200
    height: 200
    opacity: 1
    visible: true
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    clip: true
    Repeater {
        model: availableGaugePresenters
        Rectangle {
            color: "#03dac5"
            radius: 100
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                clip: true
                font.pointSize: 12
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                text: model.name
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Your example is missing the `AddGauge` type. `Unknown component.` in AddGaugeBase.qml

Comment: Sorry. I didn't add every file because I didn't want to clutter the already full-of-code post but I added AddGauge and AddGaugeForm. The form files are technically "ui.qml" files.

Comment: TestGaugeStyle is just a red rectangle. Just something that is obvious when it gets added to the SwipeView.